# Difference in creating an instance between VB.NET & C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, instantiation

I am converting some code from VB.NET to C#. In VB.NET, I have this code:

```
Dim ind As Foo.Index
Dim ed As Foo.Edit
ind = New Foo.Index
ed = ind.InFunction()
```

That works. So in C# my code will look like this:

```
Foo.Index ind;
Foo.Edit ed;
ind = New Foo.Index();
ed = ind.InFunction();
```

But this doesn't work. I am sure that I did not forget to import namespaces. And now I've been wondering, is there any difference between those two?

**EDIT:**
And I finally add

```
ed = New Foo.Edit();
```

into my C# code, but it also doesn't work. IMHO, I think there is a feature in VB.NET that allows auto initializing in variables (like the comment from Bex below suggests). Is it true?

**FINAL:**
Seems I do need to show all the code. But I need to talk directly to you as well (or you just install the software of mine). It makes me really confused. Thank you all. Sorry for this kind of newbie question.

Comment: `But, it doesn't work in C#`. Well, that's VB code, I wonder how do you expect it to work in C# :-) Those are two different languages with different syntaxes.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: What does the C# code look like?

Comment: @Darin :Sorry, I've already converted it to C#. And now, in My C#, why it always be NullReferenceException pointing my ed object initialization?
i am wondering why in VB don't need "ed As New IndexServer.EditInfo" code?

Comment: @riandp - It would be better if you were to post both the VB code that worked for you, and the C# code that doesn't. In it's current state this question is liable to be closed as "Not a real question".

Comment: @Zhaph. Thank Zhaph. but I don't think it is necessary, since I am using new framework that is not publicly available now. And also the lines above have explain about my overall codes.

Answer (score 2):

C-like languages (like C#) require you follow the pattern of [*type*] [*variable name*] at a minimum. C#, using the simplest form of initialization, requires you to use the `new` keyword.

A simple C# class definition:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

Then, to initialize an instance:

```
Foo myFooIsStrong = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//instantiation

IndexServer.ClientInfo ci = new  IndexServer.ClientInfo();

IndexServer.IXServicePortC konst = new IndexServer.IXServicePortC();

IndexServer.IndexServer ix = new IndexServer.IndexServer();

IndexServer.EditInfo ed = new IndexServer.EditInfo();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you are asking but this may help.
VB auto initializes a lot of variables and c# doesn't.
So in c# you should initialize your variables.

Comment: can you clarify that with any sources? seems like it is related to my problem

Comment: erm.. well they told me it on a course a few months ago! So I've got it on paper in my course notes..! I can't find anything after a quick google! All you need to know is when you declare something in c# you have to initialize it by going ObjectType a = new ObjectType; rather than just ObjectType a; vb automatically assigns a value, c# automatically assigns as null!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that vb.net let's you import namespace roots, while C# requires you to import the full namespace. Your VB code has a statement like this at the top:

```
Imports MyLibrary
```

This puts the MyLibrary namespace sort of "in scope", such that you can use the type `MyLibrary.Foo.Index` either through the full name or by simply saying `Foo.Index`. C# does not allow this. You must either also import `MyLibrary.Foo` or reference the entire name in your code.

Answer (score 1):

C# is case sensitive. So the

```
ed = New Foo.Edit();
```

should be

```
ed = new Foo.Edit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
using IndexServer;

...

IndexServer ix = new IndexServer();
ClientInfo ci = new ClientInfo();
EditInfo ed = ix.checkoutSord(ci, Konstanta.EDIT_INFO.mbSord, Konstanta.LOCK.NO);
```

Without knowing what those classes look like, hard to tell you more. But instantiation is basically the same, just need to change some syntax for declaring variable.